# Is there a way to Block opened ports in php?

Tags: php

Is there a way to Block opened ports in php?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you are`trying to do and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are talking about networking ports, you have to be root for that in a linux environment. if you can run the script as the root and give the running process to play with the ports, yes.

is it possible? yes.

but not recommend it.